# Reading exactly 4 characters from user, using `std::cin`, into a character array

Tags: c++, arrays, io

I want to read 4 characters from user, using `std::cin`, into a character array, and if enters more than 4 characters then to display error.

So I thought about creating a char array of length 4 and to do something like:

```
char input[4] = "";
std::cin >> input;
```

But how can I check If he enters more than 4 characters? And if he enters more than 4 characters, won't it over-write the memory after `input[4]`?

Comment: You probably better use `std::string` for input, and check if `length() == 4` after input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use std::string;

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);

if(s.size() != 4)
{
    //ERROR
}
```

Comment: and how do I check if more than 4 were entered?

Comment: @ManoMini: Why? What's wrong with using the right tool for the job? Although this answer is flawed in a few ways (newlines!!)

Comment: @ManoMini You can (if you really insist) to use [`std::cin::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) (overload #3), then ignore and clear the rest of the stream. However using a `std::string` is the most obvious way to go here.

Comment: @ManoMini, you can use C-language analogs of std::string, but it will make code much more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

**Possible Solution:**

You can use a string for this purpose.

**Code:**

```
std::string input = "";
std::getline(std::cin,input);

if(input.size() > 4)
    std::cout << "Error";
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is using cin.get(), as follows:

```
char input[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    cin.get(input[i]);
}
```

It is worth mentioning that if you don't need to use C-style strings, a more elegant approach would be using an std::string:

```
std::string input = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    input += cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `std::string` is to use the

[`std::basic_istream& std::basic_istream::get( char_type* s, std::streamsize count )`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)

overload, then discard the rest of the input stream and clear its error flags, like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    const std::size_t buf_size = 5;
    char buf[buf_size];
    std::cin.get(buf, buf_size); // reads buf_size-1 chars from std::cin and adds a '\0'

    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
}
```